# Using tempfile as source for wxPython image widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, temporary-files

I'm using pyplot.savefig to save a matplotlib figure as a .png and this code works:

```
pyplot.savefig('tempfile.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
i = wx.Image('tempfile.png', 'image/png', -1)
i.Resize(size=(500,500), pos=(0,0), red=255, green=255, blue=255)
png = i.ConvertToBitmap()
self.xrayImage = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, png, (380,10), (500,500))
```

I don't want to have this tempfile.png stick around after the program executes though, ideally it wouldn't even show up in the user's environment. I've been trying to use python's tempfile feature but keep getting invalid image, or not a .png image from the i.Resize line. I've tried using tempfile.TemporaryFile and tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile but neither have been working. Here's a few samples of what I've tried:

```
temp_png = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png')
pyplot.savefig(temp_png)
i.wx.Image(temp_png, 'image/png', -1)
i.Resize(size=(500,500), pos=(0,0), red=255, green=255, blue=255)
png = i.ConvertToBitmap()
self.xrayImage = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, png, (380,10), (500,500))
```

and:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix=".png") as tmpfile:
    pyplot.savefig(tmpfile)
    tmpfile.seek(0)
    i = wx.Image(tmpfile, 'image/png', -1)
    # also tried:
    # i = wx.Image(tmpfile.read(), 'image/png', -1)
    # i = wx.Image(b64encode(tmpfile.read()), 'image/png', -1)
    i.Resize(size=(500,500), pos=(0,0), red=255, green=255, blue=255)
png = i.ConvertToBitmap()
self.xrayImage = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, png, (380,10), (500,500))
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm also open to not using python's tempfile as long as there is no file left on the user's computer.

Comment: Did you try using a simple BytesIO buffer?

Comment: Yes, just implemented it with user nepix32's guidance, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by User `ImportanceOfBeingEarnest`: Get rid of the the tempfile altogether and use a buffer to store the result of `savefig` (tested with wxPython 4.0.1)

```
import wx

from io import BytesIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

def get_pyplot_img():
    rc('savefig', format='png')
    buf = BytesIO()
    plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 4], '-')
    plt.savefig(buf)
    # reset buf pointer
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf

def get_bitmap(buf):
    img = wx.Image(buf, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
    return wx.Bitmap(img)
```

Comment: UPDATE: worked beautifully, I think it's even faster now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just delete the image file once you have displayed it?

```
import wx
import os
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args)
        plt.plot([1.5,2.0,2.5])
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.savefig("/tmp/myimg.png", transparent=True)
        aText = wx.StaticText(self,-1,("My Image Display"))
        img = wx.Image("/tmp/myimg.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        Image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, bitmap=wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(aText,0,0,0)
        sizer.Add(Image,1,0,0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()
        self.Show()
        os.remove("/tmp/myimg.png")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    myframe = TestFrame(None, -1, "Image Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Yes, that's the solution I'm using currently but I'm worried about them being there if the program crashes unexpectedly. They're confidential images so having them show up wouldn't be great. If I can't get a solution working though that'll have to do! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem trying to save a wx.Bitmap to a temporary file created with tempfile.TemporaryFile. wx.Bitmap.SaveFile() return False and I don't know why.

As a workaround I used a temporary folder and it worked. Something along the lines of:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as directory:
  success = image.SaveFile(directory + "\\temp.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
  if success:
    do_something_with_the_picture(directory + "\\temp.png")
```